# Can thymeleaf be used with user supplied templates safely?

Tags: thymeleaf

In a SaaS application I have some templates that are used in order to generate notification emails or certain HTML pages. So far I am not using thymeleaf and so far all the templates are hard coded, but I'd love to change that, so that users of the application can edit those templates by themselves. The thing is that if I allow users to edit templates themselves, the users can possibly call any Java method and that would totally compromise system security.

Can thymeleaf be "sandboxed" or can all features that are dangerous in the context of user edited templates be disabled? (For execution the template receives a POJO with only getters and setters or a java.util.Map, so calling methods on the model is not a problem)

## What I tried

The most obvious problem is OGNL/SpringEL. The power these expressions have can be great, but they are also very dangerous. All I need is to call getters from the model. So I tried to implement my own expression parser like this (the following is just something quick&dirty as a proof of concept, it is not "done"):

```java
final TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
final StandardDialect dialect = new StandardDialect();
dialect.setExpressionParser(new IStandardExpressionParser() {
    @Override
    public IStandardExpression parseExpression(final IExpressionContext context, final String input) {
        if (!input.startsWith("${") || !input.endsWith("}")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only variable expressions allowed, not " + input);
        }
        final String[] path = StringUtils.split(input.substring("${".length(), input.length() - "}".length()), '.');
        return new IStandardExpression() {
            @Override
            public String getStringRepresentation() {
                return "Variable " + Arrays.toString(path);
            }

            @Override
            public Object execute(final IExpressionContext context) {
                Object result = context.getVariable(path[0]);
                for (int i = 1; i < path.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        result = BeanUtils.getProperty(result, path[i]);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        throw new Error(e);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public Object execute(final IExpressionContext context, final StandardExpressionExecutionContext expContext) {
                return execute(context);
            }
        };
    }
});
templateEngine.setDialect(dialect);
System.out.println(templateEngine.process(
    "<html xmlns:th=\"http://www.thymeleaf.org\"><p th:text=\"${someVar}\"></p></html>",
    new Context(Locale.ENGLISH, Collections.singletonMap("someVar", "someValue"))
));
```

And it looks like that works, but will this be enough? Or are there other security holes?

Answer (score 0):

I think your use case is better solved using Java Security Manager. You will b able to give very narrow permissions for code responsible for loading, parsing and interpreting user templates.